# Windows forms drag and minimize issue

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

This is basically what happens when I drag the window around, there was similar issue when you minimize the window and everything goes blank, but I kinda masked it by capturing the minimize event and forcing it to update everything.

Is there anything I can do about it without rewriting the whole thing from scratch? I don't know which part of the code to share, because I have no idea what  could possibly cause it.

[image]

**PS: This is a normal winforms on Windows 10.**

Comment: This doesn't look like a typical Windows window.  Is it provided by some sort of window-docking library?

Comment: @adv12 he's using the windows 10 deveolper/insider preview as far as I can see... this is a normal winforms in a future version of windows...

Comment: When do you draw the window's contents?  Do you do it within the `Paint` event handler of the form or some control within the form, or are you doing it "manually" somewhere else via `Control.CreateGraphics`?

Comment: With `Control.CreateGraphics`

Comment: Any good reason to do it this way other than not knowing that this is usally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You mention in the comments that you're drawing the control using `Control.CreateGraphics` outside of the `Paint` event.  This is bad practice, because the contents of the window may need to be refreshed for any of a number of reasons.  For instance, after your window is temporarily occluded by another window, a repaint will be triggered to redraw the area that was covered.  But since you're not doing your drawing in the `Paint` event, whatever you drew using `Control.CreateGraphics` will be erased when the control redraws itself with its default contents (basically its background color).

I recommend adding a `Paint` event handler on whatever control you draw on, and do your drawing in that handler, using the provided `Graphics` object passed in via the `PaintEventArgs`.  This event is fired immediately after the background is drawn, so whatever you draw goes on top of that.

Comment: I will look for it, I still don't understand why it is acting so weird. Nevertheless I just recently started working with those forms and I can't be familiar with the good/bad practices.